# Print PDF on web using flutter/dart/javascript

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter for web to create an application to fill in forms. I'm trying to make it so no information is ever saved to disk, only ever stored in memory.

I can't seem to find a good solution to print a PDF from byte array in javascript, so that I can call it from Dart/Flutter.

I've taken a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/tv3Cma?p=preview but the problem is that it doesn't work in chrome anymore.

```
var dataURI = "data:application/pdf;base64," +base64EncodedPDF;
window.open(dataURI);
```

Any other potential solutions I could try?

Comment: `https://pub.dev/packages/printing`  `https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/166034/how-to-print-a-pdf-document`

Answer (score -1):

PDF.js is an open-source JavaScript library that allows you to parse and render PDF files right inside your web pages. 
Here tutorial available for pdf render in web page https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pdf-viewer-in-javascript--cms-32505

Comment: Packages like that aren't compatible with Flutter

Comment: I've looked at them before, but they're not ready for the web, plus I'm looking to print in the web, not display a PDF. That's all before we are talking about a 2-10K license per platform.